# Find a such that $112_a$, $63_a$ and $34_a$ are in an arithmetic progression

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Since the formula is $a_n = a_1 + (n-1)d$ I could make $a_1 = 34_a, a_2 = 63_a$ and $a_3 = 112_a$. So what I need is a base a where the difference between $112_a$ and $63_a$ is equal to the difference between 63_a and 34_a. So I did:

$$1*a^2+1*a+2 - 6*a + 3 = 6*a+3 - 3a +4 \iff\\
a^2+a+2-a6+3 = a6+3-a3+4 \iff \\
a^2-5a+5=3a+7\iff \\
a^2-7a-2=0$$

This doesn't give me an integer solution. What went wrong?

Comment: Did you distribute the minus correctly?  It's not correct above.

Comment: $$-(6a+3)=-6a-3\ne-6a+3$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can here add without carrying (a neat trick). You know that the base is greater than $6$.

You have then $$112+34=63+63$$ so that $$146=(12)6$$

I know that doesn't address the issue with your own answer (sign wrong in workings), but I thought it worth pointing out since it works so neatly here.

Comment: Alternatively, 34 to 63 adds 3 to the "tens" place and subtracts 1 from the units place.  So the number after 63 would be 92 if not for the carry to the "hundreds" place.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Indeed you can subtract without carrying (new idea) and have negative numbers in the mix.

Comment: For (much) more exploration along these lines see https://www.explodingdots.org/

Answer (score 0):

Your approach was good, but, as commenters noticed, it should be 
$$1*a^2+1*a+2 - 6*a \color{red}- 3 = 6*a+3 - 3a \color{red}-4 \iff\\
a^2+a+2-a6\color{red}-3 = a6+3-a3\color{red}-4 \iff \\
a^2-5a\color{red}-1=3a\color{red}-1\iff \\
a^2-\color{red}8a-\color{red}0=0\iff \\
\color{red}{a(a-8)}=0.$$

So $a=0$ or $8$, but only one of those possibilities makes sense.